# Upstart - navigate to directory, git pull, then run daemontools

Tags: git, upstart

I am trying to create an upstart conf to both do a "git pull" on a local git repository and then start daemontools "svscan". They nee to be done in that order because the daemon processes rely n having the latest version of the files in the git repository.

I tried:

```
start on runlevel [12345]
respawn
pre-start script
  cd /scripts
  git pull
end script
exec /command/svscanboot
```

and also:

```
start on runlevel [12345]
respawn
chdir /scripts
exec git pull
exec /command/svscanboot
```

But neither of these work. I'm looking for help in how to tell upstart to navigate to another directory and then execute a command there, prior to running a third command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this (I had to wrap my git pull in sudo for it to work?):

```
start on runlevel [12345]

respawn

pre-start script
  export HOME="/home/user"
  cd $HOME/scripts/
  exec sudo -u user git pull
end script

script
  export HOME="/home/user"
  cd $HOME/commands/
  exec sudo -u user svscanboot >> /var/log/svscanboot.log 2>&1
end script
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using sudo -u, you can setuid

```
start on runlevel [12345]

respawn

setuid user

pre-start script
  cd /home/user/scripts/
  exec git pull
end script

script
  cd /home/user/commands/
  exec svscanboot >> /var/log/svscanboot.log 2>&1
end script
```

Comment: Not sure why, but on my system (an EC2 server with amazon's standard linux image), adding a "setuid whatever" line causes it to report "unknown job" as if it's not valid syntax :/